# How to get php to send variable to python?

Tags: php, python, html

Hello I have created a program in python that when a button is pushed it plays an audio file and it runs on a Raspberry Pi.  I have created a web page when the user can go to the IP address of the Raspberry Pi and upload an MP3's then they can select which file they would like to play.  There is some PHP code that looks over the directory to fill in the drop down list. How do I get what the user selects from the drop down list to import into a python program.  This is the HTML/PHP main page.

```html
<html>
<body>
 <h1> Welcome to the Audio Setup </h1>
 <hr />
 <h3> Use to add mp3 file to server: </h3>
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select MP3 to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
 <br />
 <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload MP3" name="submit">
</form>

<br />
<br />
<h3> Select file to play:
<hr />
<form name="sound" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/home/pi/PushButton.py">
<label for="file">Select:</label>
<select name="sound">
      <option value=""> Select File</option>
<?php 
  $dirPath = dir('/var/www/html/uploads/');
 $imgArray = array();
 while (($file = $dirPath->read()) !== false) {
     if ((substr($file, -3)=="mp3") || (substr($file, -3)=="MP3")) {
     $imgArray[] = trim($file);
  }
    }
 $dirPath->close();
 sort($imgArray);
 $c = count($imgArray);
 for($i=0; $i<$c; $i++) {
     echo "<option value=\"" . $imgArray[$i] . "\">" . 
  $imgArray[$i] . "\n";
 } 
?>
</select> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the python program that it is going into.

```html
import os
import sys
from time import sleep
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import mutagen
import cgi

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.IN)

form = cgi.sound()
if form.getvalue() != null:
    musicFile = form.getvalue()
    timer = musicFile.info.length + 1
    while True:
        if GPIO.input(23) == False:
            os.system("omxplayer -o local /var/www/html/uploads/" + musicFile)
            sleep(timer);
```

I am fairly new to programming and from what I have researched cgi is a way to transfer the selection over but maybe not the best way.  If this isn't the correct way or if there is a better way please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it but you need to build small api at python side and after you select the file from list at php side you make requests with php to your api at python

Answer (score 0):

How about a very simple solution, hopefully it does what you require.

In your php code, create a symlink from the selected file to a fixed name (http://php.net/manual/en/function.symlink.php), for example: /var/www/html/uploads/selected/1.mp3

In your python code, use the fixed name to retrieve the selected file.

Cheers